# Wrong generated TIf image using WriteableBitmap::WritePixels in c#

Tags: c#, image, tiff

I changed pixel RGB value for a TIF image, but the generated tif image is not correct.

I use C# since there are some APIS for encoding and decoding TIF image format. My code is shown below.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static int bytesPerPixel = 4;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    byte[] bytes;
    BitmapSource bitmapSource;
    FormatConvertedBitmap convertedBitmap;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    .....
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Open the selected file to read.
            string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            pictureBox1.Load(fileName);

            // Open a Stream and decode a TIFF image
            Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0]; 

            convertedBitmap = new FormatConvertedBitmap(bitmapSource, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, 0);

            bytesPerPixel = (convertedBitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;

            width = convertedBitmap.PixelWidth;
            height = convertedBitmap.PixelHeight;

            bytes = new byte[width * height * bytesPerPixel];

            convertedBitmap.CopyPixels(bytes, (convertedBitmap.PixelWidth * convertedBitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8, 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                    Color color = GetPixel(bytes, i,j, bytesPerPixel);
                    if (i < width / 2 || j < height / 2)
                        setPixel(bytes, i, j, bytesPerPixel, (byte)(0), (byte)(0), (byte)(0));
                    else {
                        setPixel(bytes, i, j, bytesPerPixel, (byte)(255), (byte)(255), (byte)(255));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static Color GetPixel(byte[] bgraBytes, int x, int y, int width)
    {
        var index = (y * (width * bytesPerPixel) + (x * bytesPerPixel));

        return Color.FromArgb(
            bgraBytes[index + 3],
            bgraBytes[index + 2],
            bgraBytes[index + 1],
            bgraBytes[index]);
    }

    private static void setPixel(byte[] bytes, int x, int y, int width, byte r, byte g, byte b) {
        var index = (y * (width * bytesPerPixel) + (x * bytesPerPixel));
        bytes[index] = r; bytes[index + 1] = g; bytes[index + 2] = b;
    }

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     ................
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            int stride = width *8;
            // Define the image palette
            BitmapPalette myPalette = BitmapPalettes.WebPalette;

            // Creates a new empty image with the pre-defined palette
            var image = new WriteableBitmap(convertedBitmap);
            image.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, convertedBitmap.PixelWidth, convertedBitmap.PixelHeight), bytes,
                (convertedBitmap.PixelWidth * convertedBitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8, 0);

            FileStream stream = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create);
            TiffBitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
            TextBlock myTextBlock = new TextBlock();
            myTextBlock.Text = "Codec Author is: " + encoder.CodecInfo.Author.ToString();
            encoder.Compression = TiffCompressOption.Zip;
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
            encoder.Save(stream);
            stream.Dispose();
        } 


    }
}
```

In the code, a tif image is read and its pixel RGB is copied to the byte[] bytes which is a class field member. After modifying all pixel RGB color (by 255 -), the bytes is then used to initilize another image and writen to the disk.

There is no error during runtime, but the generated tif image is not the same as i expected. The generated image is the same as original one, which is not correct.

Could anyone explain the reason that the generated image the same as input one? It seems the writePixel() does not take effect. During debug, i do find the `bytes` parameter in writePixel has been updated.   I do not know the reason, as i am not very skill at C#, nor Image format. The original code are from 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969817%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1
and 
[TIFF file parsing in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787739/tiff-file-parsing-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You are not inverting the image - you use only R component: "(byte)(255 - color.R), (byte)(255 - color.R), (byte)(255 - color.R)"

Comment: I am too carelessly.  After fixing this issue, the generated tif image is still the same (All are BLUE)